# Navigate all C/C++ function entries in Vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to navigate all the function definitions in a C++ source file, `]]` should be fine if all the functions are indented correctly as it required, but this might not be true for some source files,  such as functions inside namespace have extra indentation. Searching the next function block start symbol which are in the same level as the current one (such as the second top level open bracket) would be a fine workaround, I think. Is there such command or extension which does this?

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question, but you might like to check out the TagBar plugin: http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/

Comment: `foldmethod=syntax` might also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Vim as a general-purpose text editor has no deep knowledge of the various programming languages. Depending on the accuracy needed, a regular expression may already catch most common function definitions. You can then use something like my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) to make motion mappings from the patterns.

Another good source is the syntax highlighting, in particular the *folding* part. If you configure `:setlocal foldmethod=syntax`, you can use the built-in fold navigation commands (e.g. `zj` / `zk`) to navigate.

For the best accuracy, you need an external tool like `ctags` to parse the C source code and determine the function names. Plugins like *TagBar* (already mentioned in the comments) and *TagList* help you list and navigate then.

Answer (score 2):

A plugin like [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) or [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) (in combination with ctags) may help but you can do something like:

```
:vim /^\s*\w\+\s\+\w\+\s*(.*)/ % | cw
```

to populate the quickfix window with every function definition in the current file.

Alternatively, the default python ftplugin comes with a nice generic function and nice mappings that we can repurpose. Place the following lines in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
function! Custom_jump(motion) range
  let cnt = v:count1
  let save = @/
  mark '
  while cnt > 0
    silent! execute a:motion
    let cnt = cnt - 1
  endwhile
  call histdel('/', -1)
  let @/ = save
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call Custom_jump('/^\s*\w\+\s\+\w\+\s*(.*)')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call Custom_jump('?^\s*\w\+\s\+\w\+\s*(.*)')<cr>
```

Comment: thanks. Lots of unrelated parentheses also been selected out this way.

Comment: I don't do C++ so I don't have a real world sample to test it out but it seemed to work perfectly on a sample file with a namespace found online. (hmm… it will jump to `else if (` as well) If you have a sample file post it somewhere so that I could test it further.

Answer (score 0):

If your functions definition follow the pattern:

```
<return_type>

function_name (<args>..
```

OR

```
<return_type>

function_name(<args>..
```

use this in `.vimrc`:

```
map o :vim /^\w\\+\\_s(\\\\|^\w\\+(/ %\\|cw \<CR>
```

For other function definition patterns, please update accordingly, reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983039/13956953
- https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/vetter/Other-stuff/vi/vimtips.html
- https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_patterns